# Blank screen is displayed when pressing the back button to move to previous fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

when I'm pressing the back button it is moving to the previous fragment but also displaying a blank screen and I need to click it to eliminate it. How do I get rid of this blank screen? I saw its somehow connected to the first `addToBackStack` but I still couldn't fix it

here's my `onNavigationItemSelected` method:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment=new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_income:
                fragment=new IncomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_expense:
                fragment=new ExpenseFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_sign_out:
                FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mAuth.signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

        }
        if(fragment!=null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack("").commit();

        return true;
    }
```

here's my `onBackPressed()` method:

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                builder.setTitle("Sign out");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to sign out?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        firebaseAuth.signOut();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class));
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please try to remove addToBackStack("")

Comment: but then it won't return to the previous fragment

Comment: where you are getting blank screen? In every back or any specific screen back?

Comment: on every back click that's the blank screen: https://imgur.com/Uen5OLt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change if condition as per below

```
if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1 == 0){
    //Do your code
}else{
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
```

As per your code please find below full code

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1 == 0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            builder.setTitle("Sign out");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to sign out?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class));
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: Try to add some value into addToBackStack.

Comment: Are you add same onBackpressed function which I am answered?

Comment: Can you share activity layout xml?

Comment: Ok.Are you not use my onBackpressed funcation at that time?

Answer (score 0):

Update onCreateView of your all fragment

```
View view; 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
    if (view.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
    }
    return view;
}

View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tests, container, false);
```

Hope this will helps!!

Comment: what is R.layout.tests?

Comment: replace your layout xml file over there

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess It is because last fragment is getting removed and you are seeing blank screen which is fragment container where you add fragments. So, when last screen is reached please finish that activity before starting other one. Use This code for starting new Activity.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
finish();   //finish used to finish blank screen activity
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I dont want to do it with intents because I'm using fragments